# Name 'cv2_imshow' is not defined

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I try to detect face video using cv2, on Google Colab. Here is my code:

```
import cv2

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/content/drive/MyDrive/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# To capture video from webcam. 
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# To use a video file as input 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/MyDrive/deepfake-detection-master/test_videos/aassnaulhq.mp4')

while True:
    # Read the frame
    _, img = cap.read()
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Detect the faces
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    # Draw the rectangle around each face
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    # Display
    cv2_imshow(img)
    # Stop if escape key is pressed
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()
```

It gives me this error:

```
NameError: name 'cv2_imshow' is not defined
```

How can I solve this error ? Do I need to define like import cv2_imshow ?

Comment: Change the underscore to a dot, like all your other `cv2` calls.

Comment: when I change to dot the colab give error "cv2.imshow() is disabled in Colab, because it causes Jupyter sessions" instead to use cv_imshow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using cv2 as imported in your code, imshow() is a method from cv2, so just use:

```
cv2.imshow(img)
```

if you work in colab, import cv2_imshow at the beginning of the code:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
```

Comment: yeah I try it before and then give me error "cv2.imshow() is disabled in Colab, because it causes Jupyter sessions
to crash; see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3935.
As a substitution, consider using
  from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow"

Comment: I edited my answer to take this case into account.